# How to insert file path into Text Component

Tags: ignition

By using the Component Scripting - mouseReleased - Script Editor

```
path = system.file.openfile()
```

I have been able to get the following popup.
[image]

Now what I want is for the selected File's path to be inserted into the original Text Component's Text Property (properly formatted for Ignition).

Like this -

[image]

Any and all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script works perfectly.

```
path = system.file.openFile()
if path != None:
    event.source.text = path
```

We now use the following for this type application.

[image]

Comment: The following link is related to this answer.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/53711297/10166965

Comment: I've modified this script since last comment. See last Reply/Answer to open all file extensions.