# How to view all files within a folder using openFile?

Tags: python, ignition

I'm using the following code to open a dialog box to a specific folder.
It is currently displaying all .jpg files.  How do I make it show all files?

```
path = system.file.openFile('jpg', 'J:\FULLSAIL\Historian')
if path != None:
```

[image]

Comment: `import glob; print(glob.glob(path+'\*'))`

Comment: You might also want to tell us what interface/library you are using there. `system.file.openFile` is not exactly standard Python.

Comment: Backslashes in literal strings need to be escaped or the string needs to have an `r` prefix added to it. i.e. `'J:\\FULLSAIL\\Historian'` _or_ `r'J:\FULLSAIL\Historian'`.

Comment: Python also doesn't have a built-in module named `system`—what is that (some part of `ignition`)?

Comment: The software interface I'm using is ignition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignition's support team said to use the following script.

```
path = system.file.openFile(None,'J:\FULLSAIL\Historian')
```

I tested and it seems to work exactly like I was hoping.
One note, the term None must be have the first N capitalized, I first tried none and the system did not recognize the cmd.
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I had to go back over this again and so far I think this to be the best way using Text Field Input in Ignition Designer

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.inductiveautomation.com/display/DOC79/system.file.openFile) says that you can specify the file extension, for instance “jpg”.

Since it probably uses glob.glob function to filter the files list, you can try with “*” to have no filtering and get all the files.

The documentation also says that the extension is an optional parameter, so you can try:

```
system.file.openFile(r”J:\FULLSAIL\Historian”)
```